# Blockchain development and top players

Tags: blockchain

what is the latest block chain development and top players with this tech, such as Digital Asset Holdings ?

I am kind of new to this subject and want to have a brief understanding. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, this is not your free homework solving service. Please come back, when you have a concrete, technical question.

Answer (score 0):

The blockchain technology still has a few challenges to solve, it really depends what is important for you. Some projects have focus on performance like https://www.hyperledger.org/ other on privacy http://www.enigma.co/   others on business: http://www.r3cev.com/projects/

To understand blockchain well, you need to get down to the mechanism and understand the current issues with the decentralisation, performance, scalability, proof of work, reliability and privacy. for each of those points there are projects trying to solve. 
Here is a good intro: https://blog.plan99.net/the-resolution-of-the-bitcoin-experiment-dabb30201f7